# Proper Use Of Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to know if I am properly using Fragments here...

My application contains 6 Activities. I wanted to add a Navigation Drawer to it so I am currently in the process of converting each of these Activities to Fragments. When I select an option from the Drawer, the appropriate Fragment will appear. 
My Fragments are very "stand alone" meaning each Fragment is self contained and not interacting with other Fragments, for example a calendar that displays the date.

[image]

This would look the same on every device, whether a tablet or phone. EVERY tutorial I have seen about Fragments has multiple Fragments interacting with one another. Mine does not. My question is, from a design perspective, is it ok to use Fragments in this manner? Or should I just use Activities instead? Thank You.

Comment: yes it is. it will help you if in the future (e.g on a wide screen tablet) you want to show another fragment next to this one.

Answer (score 1):

If it is from the drawer, the proper design is to use fragments. You should be using Fragments whenever it's possible, as it makes your code easier to maintain and control. Communication between fragments are easier than communicating between activities.

In addition, activities are expensive to operate. Activities created also do not implicitly destroy previous activities.

Comment: How do Fragments make one's code 'easier to maintain and control'? 
How is communication between Fragments 'easier' than between Activities? 
And in what respect are Activities 'expensive to operate' compared to fragments?

Comment: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Android-Design/

This guy's got a whole presentation on this stuff... check it out. Also try looking at other stackoverflow threads, lots of discussion has been had about this in the past.

Comment: I use activities to manage fragments and fragments to manage content. Even when I only have to show a single image, I will inflate it inside a fragment and embed that inside an activity. Fragments are also more lightweighted (subjective impression of mine). Like this, I have a good separation of concern and I think OP is doing the right move in converting each of his activites into fragments. Of course OP has one activity hosting the whole navigation drawer, where he can also fix the layout to portrait etc. This is what works best for me.